# Could not find Dependecy In React-native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to integration native android SDK into react-native app,

Trying to implement the dependency, but unfortunately on `./gradew build` terminal is throwing the error of

```
    Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.cuelinks.sdk:link-kit:1.0.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Following is my app level `build.gradle` file,

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

react {
    
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.cuelinkssdkintegration"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cuelinkssdkintegration"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1")
    implementation("com.cuelinks.sdk:link-kit:1.0.3")

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Solutions tried

1. using `./gradlew clean` command proceed with `npx react-native run-android`
2. Tried invalidate cache restart
3. Delete nodes and re-install

P.S this dependency is properly implementing in my native android project.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,

JCenter() was missing in allprojects level.